# Change tint color in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, vector, android-vectordrawable

I want to change color of vector image at runtime.

XML example (ImageView):

```
app:tint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
```

How do I change this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setColorFilter

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```